# NSNotificationCenter observer receives different number of notifications each run

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch, nsnotificationcenter

I am running two different `dispatch queues` concurrently, looping through 365 iterations and instancing an object. That loop adds the object to the `NSNotificationCenter`, and then the object posts a notification once the it's event store async code block is completed. The issue that I have, is that I should receive 730 messages in the debugger, but I don't. Each time I run the app, I receive a varying number of messages, from 513 up to 630.

Is there any reason why this happens?

This is the code where I perform the loop, and add the objects to the `Notification Center`. I create an instance of `HZCalendarDay` that I add to an immutable array.

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        // Alloc / Init instance variables.
        previousDays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        futureDays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.datesOnCalendar = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.stateOfCalendarCache = StateOfEventStoreCache_CachingRequired;
        self.currentDay = [[HZCalendarDay alloc] init];

        // Setup our event store security access.
        [self setupEventStore];

        DEDateUtility *dateUtility = [[DEDateUtility alloc] init];
        NSDate *today = [dateUtility normalizedDateWithDate:[NSDate date]];
        HZCalendarDay *date = [[HZCalendarDay alloc] initOnDate:today withEventStore:self.eventStore];
        [self.datesOnCalendar addObject:date];
        self.currentDay = date;

        // Before we start caching, we need to setup the KVO so we can compile the
        // completed caches, since both previous and future days are cached separately.


        // Start caching previous days.
        dispatch_queue_t previousDaysCacheQueue = dispatch_queue_create("previousDaysCacheQueue", NULL);
        dispatch_async(previousDaysCacheQueue, ^ {
            int numberOfDays = (HZ_NUMBER_OF_TOTAL_YEARS_TO_CACHE * 365)/2;
            for (int count = 1; count < numberOfDays; count++) {
                NSDate *previousDate = [dateUtility adjustDate:today byNumberOfDays:-count];
                HZCalendarDay *calendarDay = [[HZCalendarDay alloc] initOnDate:previousDate withEventStore:self.eventStore];
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(completeCaching:) name:HZ_KVO_CALENDAR_CACHE_NOTIFICATION object:calendarDay];

                @synchronized (self.datesOnCalendar) {
                    [self.datesOnCalendar insertObject:calendarDay atIndex:0];
                }
            }
        });

        // Start caching future days.
        dispatch_queue_t futureDaysCacheQueue = dispatch_queue_create("futureDaysCacheQueue", NULL);
        dispatch_async(futureDaysCacheQueue, ^ {
            int numberOfDays = (HZ_NUMBER_OF_TOTAL_YEARS_TO_CACHE * 365)/2;
            for (int count = 1; count < numberOfDays; count++) {
                NSDate *futureDate = [dateUtility adjustDate:today byNumberOfDays:count];
                HZCalendarDay *calendarDay = [[HZCalendarDay alloc] initOnDate:futureDate withEventStore:self.eventStore];
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(completeCaching:) name:HZ_KVO_CALENDAR_CACHE_NOTIFICATION object:calendarDay];

                @synchronized (self.datesOnCalendar) {
                    [self.datesOnCalendar addObject:calendarDay];
                }
            };
        });
    }

    return self;
}
```

In the same class, I have the method that my `NSNotificationCenter` posts to, and the setter of `cacheStage` `NSLogs` the current value. It should eventually equal 730, but it never gets that high.

```
- (void)setCachingStage:(NSInteger)cachingStage {
    _cachingStage = cachingStage;
    NSLog(@
          "Cache Stage: %d", _cachingStage);

    if (_cachingStage == (HZ_NUMBER_OF_TOTAL_YEARS_TO_CACHE*365)) {
        self.stateOfCalendarCache = StateOfEventStoreCache_CachingComplete;
        NSLog(@"Caching completed.");
    }
}

- (void)completeCaching:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:HZ_KVO_CALENDAR_CACHE_NOTIFICATION object:(HZCalendarDay *)notification.object];
    self.cachingStage++;
}
```

This is the initializer for the `HZCalendarDay`, that then grabs a cache of events and reminders. Once the events and reminders are setup, it `Posts` to the `NotificationCenter`.

```
- (void)setCacheStage:(NSInteger)cacheStage {
    _cacheStage = cacheStage;

    if (_cacheStage == 2) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:HZ_KVO_CALENDAR_CACHE_NOTIFICATION object:self];
    }
}

- (id)initOnDate:(NSDate *)date withEventStore:(EKEventStore *)eventStore {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.events = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        self.reminders = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        self.date = date;
        self.eventStore = eventStore;

        [self fetchAllEvents];
        [self fetchAllReminders];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)fetchAllEvents {
    NSPredicate *fetchPredicateForEvents = [self.eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:[self startTime] endDate:[self endTime] calendars:[self.eventStore calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent]];
    self.events = [self.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:fetchPredicateForEvents];

    // Don't store a nil array in the dictionary.
    if (!self.events) {
        self.events = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    }

    self.cacheStage++;
}

- (void)fetchAllReminders {
    NSPredicate *fetchPredicateForReminders = [self.eventStore predicateForIncompleteRemindersWithDueDateStarting:[self startTime] ending:[self endTime] calendars:[self.eventStore calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder]];
    [self.eventStore fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:fetchPredicateForReminders completion:^(NSArray *reminders) {
        @synchronized (self.reminders) {
            self.reminders = reminders;
        }
        self.cacheStage++;

    }];
}
```

Can someone explain to me what might be going wrong? Is this related to the multiple threads? If so, is there a better way for me to let the class that is instancing the objects know that the objects has cached the event store reminders? This class is the datasource for my UITableView, and so I need to have the reminders cached and someway to let my datasource know that caching was accomplished. This allows my UI to display a "refreshing" or loading indicator on it while the caching takes place.

Comment: A quick note, if I replace the calendarDay object as the NotificationCenter with a nil argument, then the notification center spams the console with thousands of NSLog's. I'm not sure why NSNotificationCenter isn't working the way it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are implementing `cachingStage` is not thread-safe.  Please note that merely wrapping the implementation of `cachingStage`/`setCachingStage:` in `@synchronized` is not sufficient in this case, because you do this:

```
self.cachingStage++;
```

...which is actually the equivalent of:

```
NSInteger foo = self.cacheStage; foo++; self.cacheStage = foo;
```

When you do this with two threads A & B, the following can happen:

1. Thread A reads the current value, `x`, into `foo`.
2. Thread A is pre-empted and put to sleep.
3. Thread B reads the current value, `x`, into `foo`, increments `foo` to `x + 1`, and writes it back into `cachingStage`, does a bunch of other stuff, and is eventually pre-empted.
4. Thread A resumes, increments it's `foo` to `x + 1`, and writes that value back into `cachingStage`.

At this point, you expect `cachingStage` to be `x + 2`, but it's not. It's `x + 1`. If you think about that, it perfectly explains why your value is never getting as high as you think it should. You need to explicitly protect any data/state that can be manipulated from multiple threads. Instead of `setCachingStage:`, in this case, you probably want a method like `incrementCachingStage` which you might then implement like this:

```
- (void) incrementCachingStage {
    @synchronized(self) {
        _cachingStage++;
        NSLog(@"Cache Stage: %d", _cachingStage);

        if (_cachingStage == (HZ_NUMBER_OF_TOTAL_YEARS_TO_CACHE*365)) {
            self.stateOfCalendarCache = StateOfEventStoreCache_CachingComplete;
            NSLog(@"Caching completed.");
        }
    }
}
```

That's just one piece of data, though, and you've got a bunch here, some/all of which may need to be made thread-safe.